# PHPEXCEL : how to merge cells dynamically based on count

Tags: php, loops, phpexcel

I want to merge cells dynamically based on count using PHPEXCEl.

For example:

if `$count = 2;`
I want to merge two cells as given below,

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:B1');
```

similarly, if `$count = 4;`

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('C1:F1');
```

similarly, if `$count = 5;`

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('G1:K1');
```

I want to get this logic in a loop.

I tried the below logic, which doesn't work

```
$count = ew_Execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ems_defects_codes WHERE DEF_CODE = '$def_code'");
$start_letter = A;
$rowno = 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < $count ; $i++) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($start_letter.$rowno.':'.$i.$rowno);
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.Thanks..!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get column range string value for the inputs - start_letter, row_number and count. Once the column range is available, same can be used in the PHPExcel mergeCells function. Here is example code to get column range:

```
function getColRange($start_letter, $row_number, $count) {

    $alphabets = range('A', 'Z');
    $start_idx = array_search(
        $start_letter,
        $alphabets
    );

    return sprintf(
        "%s%s:%s%s",
        $start_letter,
        $row_number,
        $alphabets[$start_idx + $count],
        $row_number
    );
}

print getColRange('A', 1, 2) . PHP_EOL;
print getColRange('C', 1, 4) . PHP_EOL;
print getColRange('G', 1, 4) . PHP_EOL;
```

Output

```
A1:C1
C1:G1
G1:K1
```

Further you can use this new function with your code to do actual merge. You can choose to call this function or in a loop.

```
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->mergeCells(
    getColRange(
        $start_letter,
        $row_number,
        $count
     )
 );
```

Comment: Getting error when i try the above logic  **Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\asset_tracker1v04_ems_report\phpexcel180\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 857**

Comment: @AnilKumarReddy The error indicates that the PHP process is trying to allocate memory beyond what is allowed. Do you have any loop in your code which is running infinitely? Can you paste complete code at the end of your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `$i` inside of your loop is always going to be an integer; you need to convert that integer to the corresponding index of the alphabet, by creating an alphabetic array. This can be done with a simple `range('A', 'Z')`.

You also need to wrap the `A` in `$start_letter` in apostrophes (as `'A'`), and now that the range has been created, you can simply use the index of the alphabet for that:
`$start_letter = 0` (later becoming `'A'` with `$alphabet[$start_letter]`).

Then you'll need to **add** the starting letter to the count for in order to get the ending cell in `mergeCells()`. Your starting cell now becomes `$alphabet[$start_letter] . $rowno`, and your ending cell now becomes `($alphabet[$start_letter] + $alphabet[$i]) . $rowno`.

This can be seen in the following:

```
$count = ew_Execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ems_defects_codes WHERE DEF_CODE = '$def_code'");
$alphabet = range('A', 'Z');
$start_letter = 0;
$rowno = 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($alphabet[$start_letter] . $rowno . ':' . ($alphabet[$start_letter] + $alphabet[$i]) . $rowno);
}
```